# How to exit from the accept method of serversocket?

Tags: java, sockets, http, webserver

I want to shutdown the *HTTP threadpooled server*. For that I make one thread that is listening STDIN.
If I type `shutdown`, it shutdown the server.

**Code is**

```
public class WebServerShutdown extends Thread{

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger( WebServerShutdown.class.getName() );

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            //ThreadPool threadpool = new ThreadPool();
            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null && s.length() != 0) {
                System.out.println(s);
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown")) {
                    ThreadPool.isStopped = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.info(new Date() + " Problem in reading Input from keyboard");
        }
        System.out.println("Thread comes out");
    }
 }
```

**Code where server listens**

```
    while( !(ThreadPool.isStopped) ) {
        Socket client_socket = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("try to accept socket");
            client_socket = serversocket.accept();
        } catch(IOException ie) {
            log.info(new Date() + " Server Stopped");
        }
        ThreadPool.threads.execute(new Worker(client_socket));          
    }

    System.out.println("Reached here");

ThreadPool.threads.shutdown();
serversocket.close();

log.info(new Date() + " WEBSERVER STOPPED");
```

But there is one problem, when I write shutdown, at that time server enters in the loop and listening  for client's request. So, when I give any client request, after that it closes the server.

But that is not good. I want whenever I write shutdown, it does not take any other client request.

Help me to make above code correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `serversocket closes` the socket, then `accept` exception should be catch by `SocketException` and this is as follows,

**WebServerShutdown class**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown")) {
                ThreadPool.isStopped = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.info(new Date() + " Problem in reading Input from keyboard");
    }
    System.out.println("Thread comes out");
    try {
        WebServer.serversocket.close();
    } catch(IOException ie) {
        log.info(new Date() + " Problem in closing socket");
    }
}
```

**Code where server listens**

```
     while( !(ThreadPool.isStopped) ) {
            Socket client_socket = null;
            try {
                client_socket = serversocket.accept();

            } catch(SocketException se) {
                log.info(new Date() + " WEBSERVER STOPPED");
            }

            if(ThreadPool.isStopped) break;
            ThreadPool.threads.execute(new Worker(client_socket));          
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `Close()` method of your ServerSocket, but outside that thread. When you call that method is going to throw an IOException in the `accept()`, which you catch and then you call `break;` to stop that loop.

```
     if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown")) {
                                ThreadPool.isStopped = true;
                                ClassListening.ServerSocket.close();
                                break;
        }

// Break the loop where the ServerSocket was listening

            try {
                        System.out.println("try to accept socket");
                        client_socket = serversocket.accept();
                    } catch(IOException ie) {
                        log.info(new Date() + " Server Stopped");
                        break;
                    }
```